# Issue when retrieving the AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore always returns null in implementing smart target with DD4T.net

Tags: dd4t, smarttarget

The issue which i am facing is 
`ClaimStore claimStore = AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore;

```
        if (claimStore != null)
        {
            query = AmbientDataHelper.GetTriggers(claimStore);
        }`
```

always returns null i have install ADF in my .net application using [link](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B513935A-2C58-42F3-A958-FB3E620C7812?#docid=GUID-3208B26D-5A4D-4DEE-B26F-5742F952FD3B&filename=GUID-3208B26D-5A4D-4DEE-B26F-5742F952FD3B.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-3208B26D-5A4D-4DEE-B26F-5742F952FD3B)
Please suggest

Comment: Did you check the logs already? If not...

Comment: 2015-02-04 18:22:34,770 DEBUG Deployer - Running deployer XSLT to guarantee configuration format
2015-02-04 18:22:34,771 DEBUG Deployer - Running Configuration XSLT: xslt/cd_deployer_conf.xsl
2015-02-04 18:22:35,231 INFO  Deployer - Configuration: cd_deployer_conf.xml xslt has run
2015-02-04 18:22:35,341 ERROR XMLConfigurationReader - Error while validating file 'null' with schema 'schemas/cd_deployer_conf.xsd'. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Properties'. One of '{TagBundle}' is expected.

Comment: That looks like the deployer log, how about your web application log

Comment: This is web application log 

Start claimStore for region: Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.ClaimStore
2015-02-04 20:30:33,119 [11] DEBUG Logger [(null)] - Start GetTriggers for region: &taf_request_full_url=http%3A%2F%2Fsmarttargetdd4t%2Findexpage.html&taf_tracking_id=tridion_ceebeb60-83f9-458f-ac59-3019dd2ed658&taf_response_cookie_generation=true
2015-02-04 20:30:33,178 [11] DEBUG Logger [(null)] - Start sb.ToString():

Comment: Is that the full log? It might be easier to post it as part of the question, or link to it on a filesharing site, rather than squeezing it in the comments (its easier to read then also). It looks like ADF/Smart Target is operating OK from the snippet you show however...

Comment: Hi Will ,
The query shown in log is: INFO Query - Executing query: fh_location=//catalog01/en_US

Please suggest

Comment: Which Tridion version are you using? In 2011 there may be a threading issue. Can you also post a longer part of the log where you actually see what's set in the claimstore and all surrounding relevant log lines?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like AmbientData framework is not setup on the your website Or you are not executing it from the website where AmbientFramework is applied... Can you double check it?